# Allow fullscreen on embed video using redirection with masking

Tags: html, iframe, embed, url-masking

I am currently using the following video code on our website resp. landing page:

```
<div style="position: relative; display: block; max-width: 960px;"><div style="padding-top: 56.25%;">
<iframe src="<VIDEOSOURCE>" allowfullscreen=""
    webkitallowfullscreen=""
    mozallowfullscreen=""
    allow="encrypted-media" 
    style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</iframe></div></div>
```

If I call up this page directly, I can open the video in full screen. I set up a subdomain which redirects to this landing page with masking. Page 1012312.system.com becomes start.company.com.

**The problem now**: If a visitor accesses the page via the subdomain resp. forwarding with masking, the video cannot be played in full screen anymore.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I'm facing the same one now :(

Comment: Unfortunately I had to implement it differently. I still do not have a solution for this problem.